# how to print specific pages from FlowDocumentReader

Tags: wpf, printing

I have FlowDocument reader which is bind to FlowDocument.
I want to print specific pages, but when i call printdialog field for number of pages to print is inactive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable the page range control, you can set `UserPageRangeEnabled` to `true` then show the dialog, as shown below:

```
var pd = new PrintDialog();
pd.UserPageRangeEnabled = true;
if(pd.ShowDialog() == true)
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

[Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/PrintDialog.cs)